# How to connect to the Tor network using Phantomjs, selenium and c#

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, tor

I am trying to automate a website on a .onion site using PhantomJS and Tor. Does anyone have any idea how to connect to the network?

Comment: So, were you able to use Tor network from PhantomJS?

Comment: I wasnt able to use phantomJS but I was able to use the tor browser with selenium by changing the path to the firefox browser to the launcher for tor browser. I also had to sleep the thread for a certain amount of time after launching the browser to give tor time to connect to the network. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

Tor client creates a local socks proxy server at 127.0.0.1:9050

Therefore you should start PhantomJS pointing it to that proxy:

```
phantomjs --proxy-type=socks5 --proxy=127.0.0.1:9050 script.js
```

Comment: How would I do that when starting phantomjs through c#? Everything I try gives me "Unable to connect to remote server"

Comment: Define `Everything`, preferably by adding what you tried into the question. Also, are you able to use Tor in your browser?